# Swagger, YAML: Request and Response object models are same except one field

Tags: enums, yaml, swagger, openapi

I'm defining swagger definitions for an API and I came across this use case.

The request and the response object model definitions look exactly the same.
However, there is one field in the object which returns more enum values during the get operation but restricts to minimal enum values for the put operation. Is it possible to reference different enum values for the same field conditionally thus avoiding duplicate definitions. I do not want to recreate the entire model definitions for request and response for the sake of overcoming this limitation.

Here is my example,

```
definitions:
  EntryRequest:
    properties: 
      entries:
        $ref: '#/definitions/EntityResponse/properties/entries'
  EntryResponse:
    properties:
      entries:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Entry'
  Entry:
    properties:
      entryStatus:
        type: string
        enum:
          - ENABLE
          - DISABLE
          - IN_PROGRESS
```

In the above, there are two things that I'm worried about.
1) For EntryRequest, the API accepts only ENABLE/DISABLE for PUT operation while the API returns all of them in the GET operation. I would like to create a reference to the entryStatus property conditionally. Is it possible?
2) Also, everything except the entryStatus is same for both the EntryRequest and EntryResponse object model. I do not want to duplicate that as well for the sake of representing the differention of entryStatus field.

Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT:**
As I learn more on this, I get a feeling that this is more an yaml related query. But I would like to have it here to see if anyone has faced a similar situation and how they have handled it. Or to see if I get any recommendations on how to handle this.
For tagging different enums to the same field, I think I can do like this,

```
RequestEntryStatus:
  type: string
  enum: &requestStatus
    - ENABLE
    - DISABLE

ResponseEntryStatus:
  type: string
  enum:  &responseStatus
    - ENABLE
    - DISABLE
    - IN_PROGRESS

Entry:
  properties:
    entryStatus: *requestStatus
```

But still this would enforce me to create duplicates of request and response objects with different mapping to the entryStatus field. I would like to know if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: facing a similar issue here, how did you solve?

Comment: Any update on this in newer versions?

Answer (score 1):

> The request and the response object model definitions look exactly the same. However, there is one field in the object which returns more enum values during the get operation but restricts to minimal enum values for the put operation. **Is it possible to reference different enum values for the same field conditionally thus avoiding duplicate definitions.** I do not want to recreate the entire model definitions for request and response for the sake of overcoming this limitation.

No, it's not possible.

If you want to avoid duplication, you can use a single model with all the enum values, but document verbally in the `description` that certain values are only used in the responses but not the requests.